# How to keep object alive in background in flutter?

Tags: flutter, bluetooth, iot, flutter-bloc, flutter-background

I have a requirement to connect the Bluetooth to perform read/write operation from the vehicle cluster in background. After killing the app bluetooth connection is disconnecting. I'm using flutter blue plus plugin for BLE connection.

I have to send the request to vehicle cluster in background even after killing the app through BLE connection.

Please help me to find the solution as I'm new to flutter & IOT development.

Comment: Have you tried using [flutter_background](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_background)?